# CSS position select box overridden

Tags: css, position

I want to have dropdown select box under `Programs` menu, but its been overridden, please refer to image attached:

[image]

**Edited:**
Here's my code for select box

```
<div class="slide" style="width:738px;">
    <div class="n_title_black" style="padding-left:0;">PROGRAMS</div>
    <div class="inner-main_content3" style="height:420px;padding:10px 0;">

    <div style="text-align: right; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 90px; left: -6px; z-index: 9;" id="selectGenre">
    Genre:
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" id="filterGenre" name="filterGenre" style="width:220px">
        <option selected="selected" value="all">All</option>
        <option value="7">Info/Edutainment</option>
        <option value="8">News/Investigation</option><option value="12">Life Style</option>
    </select>

    // php code below to loop video's thumb

</div> 

</div>
</div>
```

For some reason I cannot simply add the box in same  with `Programs` menu, I hope someone here can give a solution on this issue, thanks.

Comment: Instead of `left: -6px` maybe you should have a large positive value

Comment: what is your html structure?

Comment: can you give us more code, specifically where Programs is..

Comment: I have added whole code for `Programs` block, pls see my post again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not setting proper `position` property for element
Try this:

```
<div class="slide" style="width:738px;">
    <div class="n_title_black" style="padding-left:0; position:relative;">PROGRAMS</div>
    <div class="inner-main_content3" style="height:420px;padding:10px 0;position:ralative;">

    <div style="text-align: right; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:   
          10px; left: 0px; z-index: 9;" id="selectGenre">
    Genre:
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" id="filterGenre" name="filterGenre" style="width:220px">
        <option selected="selected" value="all">All</option>
        <option value="7">Info/Edutainment</option>
        <option value="8">News/Investigation</option><option value="12">Life Style</option>
    </select>

    // php code below to loop video's thumb

       </div> 

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still not work, its might the left nav menu causes the problem